# Creating theme in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

I'm new to SharePoint and I have to create custom theme that is required by the client. 
 
Can anyone point me the right direction? 
I'm using SharePoint 2016.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I hope you need to create a Custom master page right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with creating your theme/html template in html and then converting it to a Master Page in SharePoint.

You can get started here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370.aspx

A blog post on the same topic : http://blog.navantis.com/creating-a-new-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013/

The links are for SharePoint 2013 but should work for SharePoint 2016 too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is SharePoint Themes.

> Themes provide a quick and easy way to apply lightweight branding to a
>   SharePoint site. A theme lets a site owner, or a user who has designer
>   rights, customize a site by changing the site layout, color palette,
>   font scheme, and background image.

More Information here:

[SharePoint Themes Overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/themes-overview-for-sharepoint)

[Branding SharePoint sites in the SharePoint add-in model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/branding-sharepoint-sites-sharepoint-add-in)